# How to sum columns in pandas and add the result into a new row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sum, append, row

In this code I want to sum each column and add it as a new row.
It does the `sum` but it does not show the new row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(g, columns=('AWA', 'REM', 'S1', 'S2'))
df['xSujeto'] = df.sum(axis=1)
xEstado = df.sum(axis=0)
df.append(xEstado, ignore_index=True)
df
```

[image]

Comment: `append` is not an inplace operation. You need to assign it back to the original `DF`, like `df = df.append(xEstado, ignore_index=True)`.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AWA':[1,2,3],
                   'REM':[4,5,6],
                   'S1':[7,8,9],
                   'S2':[1,3,5]})

#add 1 to last index value 
print (df.index[-1] + 1)
3  

df.loc[df.index[-1] + 1] = df.sum()
print (df)
   AWA  REM  S1  S2
0    1    4   7   1
1    2    5   8   3
2    3    6   9   5
3    6   15  24   9
```

Or [append from comment of `Nickil Maveli`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621239/how-to-sum-columns-in-pandas-and-add-the-result-into-a-new-row/39621278#comment66548153_39621239):

```
xEstado = df.sum()
df = df.append(xEstado, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   AWA  REM  S1  S2
0    1    4   7   1
1    2    5   8   3
2    3    6   9   5
3    6   15  24   9
```